# SpeedCubing stopwatch in JS

Tags: javascript, html

In the code block there is a timer built. And right now the timer starts/stops with a button, but I need it to run when the space button is RELEASED and I need it to stop when the space button is PRESSED.  I have been trying to figure this one out for about two days now and I cant seem to find a solution. Every time I try to stop the timer it starts again when I release the space button.

```
let startDate;
let timeoutID = 0;
let time;
let started = false;
let timerRunOut = false;

function start(){
    if(!started){
        startDate = new Date();
        startTimer();
        started = true;
    }
}
function stop(){
    if(started){
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        started = false;
    }
}

function startTimer () {
    let current = new Date();
    time = (current - startDate);

    let timeMS = time;

    let ms = timeMS % 1000;
    timeMS = (timeMS - ms) / 1000;
    let seconds = timeMS % 60;
    timeMS = (timeMS - seconds) / 60;
    let mins = timeMS % 60;

    if(seconds < 10){
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = "0" + seconds;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = seconds;
    }

    if(mins > 0 && mins < 10){
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = "0" + mins + ":";
    }else if(mins > 0){
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = mins + ":";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = "";
    }

    if(ms < 10){
        document.getElementById("tens").innerText = "00" + ms;
    }
    else if(ms < 100){
        document.getElementById("tens").innerText = "0" + ms;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("tens").innerText = ms;
    }

    timeoutID = setTimeout(startTimer, 0);
}
```

I tried adding eventlisteners and adding in conditions, but nothing works, when the timer stops it always starts again when I release the space button.

Comment: Where is your trigger for the funtion?

Comment: I dont have one.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event

Comment: I have tried using onkeyup and onkeydown, but none of the worked the way I wanted to.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: "I need it to run when the space button is RELEASED" and "it always starts again when I release the space button", this means it works as you expected.

Comment: No I need it to stop when I press the space button and when i release it, I need it to do nothing, but when I press it again and release, I need it to start again.

Comment: You can make a flag to indicate whether the timer was runing or not, and then adjust your function call accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and I need to give a little credit to [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13970434/andr%C3%A9), he helped me figure this one out.

```
let spaceUp = 0;
function startHandler(event){
    if(event.code === "Space" && spaceUp < 1){
       start();
       spaceUp ++;
       document.addEventListener("keydown", stopHandler);
       document.removeEventListener("keyup", startHandler);
    
    }else if(spaceUp == 1){
        spaceUp = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").style.color = "black";
}
function stopHandler(event){
    if(event.code === "Space"){
        stop();
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", stopHandler);
        document.getElementById("timer").style.color = "red";
        document.addEventListener("keyup", startHandler);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", startHandler);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.code === "Space" && !started){
        document.getElementById("timer").style.color = "green";
     }
})
```